# why z-index is not working for div elements with absolute positions

Tags: html, css

Here is my website html code. I am new to html and also new to stackoverflow so I have no experience of asking question so please if there are mistakes ignore them.
I am creating a search page with fixed header and fixed left sidebar but every time i try this the main div of search shows above title div.I need help to resolve this issue.

### Here is the html code of that page

```css
header{
 display: block;
 left:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #333;
 z-index: 20;
}
body{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 width: 100%;
 bottom:0; 
 overflow: auto;

}
#main{
 clear: both;
 display:block;
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}
#fixed_top{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 z-index: 20;
}
#search_top_fixed_header{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 width: 98%;
 margin-left: 1%;
 z-index: 20;

}
#aside_wrapper{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;

 width: 30%;
 height:100%;
}
#left_aside{
 display: inline-block;
 position: fixed;
 width: 30%;
 top:200px;
 background-color: black;
 height:100%;
}
#main_search_wrapper{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 68%;
 right:1%;
 top: 200px;
 height:100%;
 background-color: brown;
}
#mains{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left:1%;
 background-color: white;
}
#search_heading{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="fixed_top">
 <div id="search_top_fixed_header">
  <header>
 <h1 id="logo">
 Naats.com
 </h1>
 <span id="search">
 <form name="header_search" id="header_search" action="" method="get">
 <input type="text" id="search_bar" name="searchq" autocomplete="off" placeholder="     search naat.com" /><button id="search_submit"></button>
 </form>
 </span>
 <span id="login_logout_header">
  <a href="#1"><img src="./images/header_login_button.png" id="header_login_button"></a><span style="display:inline;height:20px;bottom:13px;line-height:40px;position:relative;color:white">OR</span><a href="#2"><img src="./images/header_signup_button.png" id="header_signup_button"></a>

 </span>
</header>
<h1 id="search_heading">Search results for "anees ijaz"</h1>
<hr>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="mains">
 <div id="aside_wrapper">
  <aside id="left_aside">
   a
  </aside>
 </div>
 <div id="main_search_wrapper">
  a
 </div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>a
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Why not make the red box scrollable instead of resorting to fixed positions on other elements?

Comment: @Aziz thank you very much.

Comment: Why i could not think about that .........

Comment: It's ok, you're welcome and good luck!

Comment: @Aziz Yeah it works but it looks a little ugly.....  Scroll bar is only showing up in the div and also it will not be a good practice to scroll only a div...

Comment: can you give me any other solution about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue of z-index, the header part simply has a transparent background, and so when you scroll up, the red box will be moved in the viewport and will be visible under the header.

If you insist on using `fixed` positioning, you can simply add a white background to the header part by adding the following CSS:

```
#search_top_fixed_header {
  ⋮
  background: #FFF;
  top: 0;
}
```

Demo:

```css
header {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 20;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#main {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#fixed_top {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
}

#search_top_fixed_header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  z-index: 20;
  background: #FFF;
  top: 0;
}

#aside_wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left_aside {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}

#main_search_wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 68%;
  right: 1%;
  top: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}

#mains {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}

#search_heading {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- header -->
<div id="fixed_top">
  <div id="search_top_fixed_header">
    <header>
      <h1 id="logo">Naats.com</h1>
      <span id="search">
        <form name="header_search" id="header_search" action="" method="get">
          <input type="text" id="search_bar" name="searchq" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search naat.com" />
          <button id="search_submit">search</button>
        </form>
      </span>
      <span id="login_logout_header">
        <a href="#1"><img src="./images/header_login_button.png" id="header_login_button"></a>
        <span style="display:inline;height:20px;bottom:13px;line-height:40px;position:relative;color:white">OR</span>
        <a href="#2"><img src="./images/header_signup_button.png" id="header_signup_button"></a>
      </span>
    </header>
    <h1 id="search_heading">Search results for "anees ijaz"</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- main container -->
<div id="mains">

  <!-- sidebar -->
  <div id="aside_wrapper">
    <aside id="left_aside">
      a
    </aside>
  </div>

  <!-- content -->
  <div id="main_search_wrapper">
    a
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>a
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/odz66vp8/1/

P.S It is not recommended to place block-level elements such as `<form>` inside an inline element like `<span>` (semantically speaking).

Comment: Thank You very very much ......... You solved the issue in minutes while I have been fighting with this for days . Thank you once more ..